# factorial recursion "visualized" in java

Tags: java, recursion

So I have this basic factorial calculator in java but I am having trouble modifying it to fit the exercise. It says: Modify the factorial
method to print its local variable and recursive-call parameter. For each recursive call,display the outputs on a separate line and add a level of indentation. I think Im having trouble understanding where the print statements should go. So does local variable = number and recursion call parameter = number-1. Here is my code so far.

```
public class Factorial {
    private static String s1="";
    public static long factorial(long number,long save) {


    if (number <= 1) { //test for base case
        System.out.printf("%s%d! = %d*%d!=  ",s1,save,save,save-1);
        s1 = s1 +" ";
        return 1;
    }
    else{ //recursion step
        return number * factorial(number - 1,save);
    }
}

//output factorial for values 0-21
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //calculate factorials 0-21
            for (int counter = 0; counter <= 21; counter++){
                long x = factorial(counter,counter);
        System.out.printf("%d%n",x);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What would probably help this question is writing what you think the expected output should be.

Comment: yes i have the correct output now but i am having trouble formatting it. it keeps coming out on one line when it should be each line indented. i have read the format helpers but I cannot figure it out. Is that something you could help me with.

Answer (score 1):

> I think Im having trouble understanding where the print statements should go.

Yes, indeed. As you can see, the exercise states

> Modify the **factorial method** to print its local variable and recursive-call parameter.

So, modify `factorial` instead of `main`. This way, each time `factorial` is invoked, you get a new line printed out, just as the exercise asks.

Comment: Ok I have edited my code. I believe I am almost there. My only problem is the "base case" or when number == 0 I am not getting the right output. I am thinking I need to create an if statement for that case specifically? I will try it and see.

Comment: @Cake771 I would say that the problem arises from the fact that you get two base cases (0 and 1) but are talking about it as if it was a single one. If when it is 1 you return `1 * factorial(0)` you will get the expected output. So checking only once for `== 0` and not for `<= 1` should simplify your problem and give you what you want.